# gym-atari Installation Error

Tags: pip

So... The command I used to install atari.py is

```
pip install -e '.[atari]'
```

And the error log I got

```
Failed building wheel for atari-py
omit some logs...
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp  /pip-build-ajd9AF/atari-
py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',   
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-xcU5TZ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ajd9AF
/atari-py/
```

I don't know how to solve it help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The atari-py requires `cmake` installed in you computer, as cited in [README.md](https://github.com/openai/atari-py)

> #### Common issues
>
> - Make sure you have `cmake` installed. On OSX, you probably want   `brew install cmake`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14676162)

Comment: The essential part of the anwser is to verify if cmake is installed and the provided link contains basically the same information.

Comment: Should the answer be a little more direct, like install cmake, as the link does not say much more about it?

Comment: Cmake installed in my computer

Comment: cmake version 3.5.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

Comment: Strange, I installed atari-py in a clean ubuntu 16.04 docker container, the only packages needed were `python`, `python-pip`, `cmake` and `zlib1g-dev`. Could you post all the compile errors?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo pip install gym[atari]` can handle it